# The gradient at the minimum outputted by fmin_l_bfgs_b are not zero

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, scipy, gradient

I am using fmin_l_bfgs_b to approximate the minimum of a function. The problem is NOT bounded. I am using "approx_grad" to numerically get the minimum.

```
weights_sp_new, func_val, info_dict = fmin_l_bfgs_b(func_to_minimize, self.w_vectors[si][pj], 
                       args=(self.sigma_vector[si][pj], Y, X, E_step_results[si][pj]),
                       approx_grad=True, factr=10000000.0, pgtol=1e-05, epsilon=1e-04)
```

I tried it on the same objective function with different initial guesses. The outputted information dictionary is as below:

```
     information dictionary: {'nit': 180, 'funcalls': 4480, 'warnflag': 0, 
'task': b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH', 
    'grad': array([  1.69003327e+00,   2.29250366e+00,   1.55528930e+00,
                 9.84251656e-01,  -1.10133624e-02,   1.83795773e+00,
                 6.44715933e-01,   2.01643592e+00,   8.71323232e-01,
                 9.93009353e-01,   1.34615338e+00,   4.20859578e-04,
                -2.22691328e-01,  -2.13318804e-01,  -4.38475622e-01,
                 4.79004570e-01,  -4.11879746e-01,   1.71003313e+00])}


        information dictionary: {'nit': 0, 'funcalls': 20, 'warnflag': 0, 
'task': b'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL', 
    'grad': array([  1.84672949e-20,   1.49550746e-20,   1.11115003e-20,
                 2.73908962e-20,   0.00000000e+00,   2.62916240e-20,
                 0.00000000e+00,   4.95859400e-20,   4.70618521e-20,
                 4.77249742e-20,   2.80864703e-20,   0.00000000e+00,
                 1.84975333e-21,   7.63125358e-21,   1.35733459e-20,
                 6.34943656e-21,   1.02743864e-20,   5.31287405e-20])}

        information dictionary: {'nit': 107, 'funcalls': 2460, 'warnflag': 0, 
'task': b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH', 
    'grad': array([ -3.09184019,  -0.70217764,   0.72096009,  -3.23745189,
                -1.18111435,  -4.13185742,   3.90762754,   2.28011806,
                -3.02289147,  -1.21219666,   1.80007832, -12.44630606,
                -1.59126124,   1.59139978,  -1.96677574,  -0.50837465,
                 1.20439043,  -1.58858602])}

        information dictionary: {'nit': 132, 'funcalls': 2980, 'warnflag': 0, 
'task': b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH', 
    'grad': array([ -8.56568098,  -9.39712794,  -8.82591339,  -8.61912864,
                -0.53956945,  -9.46679887,   0.89827947, -10.64991782,
                -6.53652169,  -7.34566878,  -8.98861319,   1.28335021,
                -2.39830071,  -1.2056133 ,  -0.81190425,  -1.3537686 ,
                -1.65028498,  -8.30791505])}
```

You can see that it successfully gets convergence. But the gradient at the minimum are not zero. I know it means that I do not get the exact minimum. It can be descended further. What should I do now? Or can I just accept this "approximated" minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases in provided samples:

1. second run of your algorithm converged nicely, `b'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'` and as you can see

   'grad': array([  1.84672949e-20,   1.49550746e-20,   1.11115003e-20,
                    2.73908962e-20,   0.00000000e+00,   2.62916240e-20,
                    0.00000000e+00,   4.95859400e-20,   4.70618521e-20,
                    4.77249742e-20,   2.80864703e-20,   0.00000000e+00,
                    1.84975333e-21,   7.63125358e-21,   1.35733459e-20,
                    6.34943656e-21,   1.02743864e-20,   5.31287405e-20])

   is basically zero (up to 20 digits precision).
2. Remaining cases terminated due to lack of significant change in the function value, `b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'`, thus you can do one (or more) of the following:

   - decrease `factr` parameter of `fmin_l_bfgs_b`, from docs

     > **factr** : float
     >
     > The iteration stops when (f^k -
     >   f^{k+1})/max{|f^k|,|f^{k+1}|,1} <= factr * eps, where eps is the
     >   machine precision, which is automatically generated by the code.
     >   Typical values for factr are: 1e12 for low accuracy; 1e7 for moderate
     >   accuracy; **10.0 for extremely high accuracy**.
   - think about your function, maybe it can be simplified? Does it has problems with plateus (very flat surfaces) - if so, maybe you can alternate the definition to minimize the effect?
   - compute analytical gradient (thus increase precision)
   - change `epsilon` as your numerical approximation might be insufficient

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But do you mean "decrease factr parameter"? Decreasing factr leads to higher accuracy and closer to the minimum?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo, I meant decrease as it makes the stopping criterion much more tight, thus it will not stop "just because function does not change much".